# Choosing $r$ objects from $n$ identical objects, is this interpretation correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

CASE $1$:

> There are $5$ identical red balls and $5$ identical blue balls in a bag. What are the number of ways you can choose $2$ red balls and $1$ blue ball(with replacement)?

This case is simple enough as the probability of drawing any ball remains constant, so it becomes a case of tossing a coin $3$ times. The sample space would be {RRR, RRB, RBR, BRR, BBB, BBR, BRB, RBB}, and thus the answer would be $3$ ways.

CASE $2$:
Now, the case 'without replacement':
The number of balls of a certain colour changes each time you draw one. But the sample space itself remains the same as the previous case and each ball of the same colour is identical to each other, so the answer is still $3$ ways.
Even if there were $200$ red balls and $1$ blue ball, the answer would still be $3$ ways, since the act of choosing needs to produce distinct outcomes for there to be any new outcome, and since the balls are identical, nothing is changing. Therefore,

CASE $3$:

> In how many ways can you choose $r$ objects from $n$ identical objects?

The answer has to be $1$, since there is only one outcome to choose.

CASE $4$:

> There are $5$ identical red balls and $5$ identical blue balls in a bag. In a sample of $3$ balls, what is the probability that it contains $2$ red balls and $1$ blue ball?

$$P(X) = \frac{n(p).n(q)}{n(r)}$$
where $X$ is the event of choosing two red balls and one blue ball, $n(p)$ is the number of ways of choosing two red balls, $n(q)$ is the number of ways of choosing $1$ blue ball, $n(r)$ is the number of ways of choosing a sample of $3$ balls. So,$$n(p) = n(q) = 1$$$$n(r) = 8$$ from case $3$ and case $2$, since the sample space remains the same. So $$P(X) = \frac{1}{8}$$

Is this result correct? Any external perspective would help!

Comment: Consider the problem where we have a single red ball and a billion blue balls, the blue balls all of which identical.  We pull a single ball at random and we ask what the probability is that it is red.  Are you really suggesting it should be $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Be warned... $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ is a valid approach to finding probability **only** in the event that the outcomes we are counting in the sample space are equally likely to occur.  They are clearly not here.  The punchline should be that even if a counting question might talk about objects being identical... when moving to ask questions about probability for these you should treat them as distinct to help facilitate calculations.

Comment: Further, commonly in probability questions like this... the order being relevant or the order being irrelevant shouldn't matter *so long as you are consistent with your choice*.  In your incorrect attempt above, not only did you make the mistake of treating balls as identical in the probability setting when they are not... you further made the mistake of having order being relevant in the denominator while making order irrelevant for the numerator.

Comment: The final answer is that the probability of drawing two red and one blue with replacement is indeed $\frac{3}{8}$, the probability of drawing two red and one blue without replacement is $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz To your first comment, no. But the number of ways we can draw a single ball at random, that does have only two outcomes.

Comment: So what?  That is not a useful observation when considering the probability question.

Comment: Alternatively, sticking to counting equal-probability events, the probability with replacement is $\frac{5\times 5\times 5+5\times 5\times 5+5\times 5\times 5}{10\times 10\times 10}=\frac38$ and without replacement is $\frac{5\times 5\times 4+5\times 5\times 4 +5\times 4\times 5 }{10\times 9 \times 8}=\frac5{12}$ giving the same result as @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz To your 4th comment, if I'm not wrong that is hypergeometric distribution right? Aren't we using the same logic there too? But the probability changes with each draw in that case as well

Comment: And in the answer for the 'without replacement' case in your 4th comment, doesn't the combination taken work only for distinct balls? For distinct balls, choosing 3 out of 10 is different from choosing 3 out of two sets of 5 identical ones

Comment: Yes, the hypergeometric distribution is exactly the distribution described by this scenario.  Yes, if you go one draw at a time in sequence, the conditional probabilities change based on previous events.  Yes, the hypergeometric distribution correctly handles this and the form of the result where we use binomial coefficients is a good example of how order can be chosen to be considered irrelevant and still gives the same answer as if we had chosen order to be relevant, again so long as we are *consistent* with our choice and made the same choice for numerator and denominator.

Comment: If you want probabilities without replacement, getting RRB in that order is $\frac{5}{10}\times \frac{4}{9} \times\frac{5}{8} = \frac5{36}$.  RBR and BRR have the same probability making the overall figure $\frac5{12}$

Comment: "*doesn't the combination taken work only for distinct balls?*"  But when physically touching and moving and pulling balls from a bag... the balls occupy distinct positions in space and as such are in fact distinct objects.  This is whether or not they are identical *to our eyes*, they have different physical molecules which make them up.

Comment: @Henry I see, ok now I understand why it'd be 5/12. Could you also explain why my probability approach didn't work even though I went over it from the perspective of a hypergeometric distribution? The number of ways of drawing 2 red balls would've been $5 \choose 2$ in the 'distinct' case, so I extrapolated and wrote it for the identical case as 1. Could you explain what went wrong here?

Comment: @ReetJaiswal The [hypergeometric probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) would be $\frac{{5 \choose 2}{10-5 \choose 3-2}}{10 \choose 3}$ which is again $\frac5{12}$

Comment: "*I extrapolated and wrote it for the identical case as 1. Could you explain what went wrong here?*"  Again, even if they are identical to our eyes they should be treated as distinct objects for probability purposes.

Comment: @JMoravitz "even if they are identical to our eyes they should be treated as distinct objects for probability purposes" Ok, thank you I think I understand now and hopefully my understanding would improve as I attempt more problems.